# Flutter architecture question / callback functions

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I have a question about structuring the following code. It's a work in progress but it should do to illustrate my question. Basically I have a list of countdown timers (TimerEntry) with a start button. However, I want to get rid of the button logic inside the timer objects and move it up to a list of timers (TimerList), in order to do things like start timer 2 after timer 1 finishes, or stop all other timers when a new timer gets started, etc..
Like I said, I'm totally new to Flutter and I hope someone can point me in a direction of how to do that. I'm guessing some sort of custom callback function?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TimedItem extends AnimatedWidget {
  TimedItem({this.task, this.timeRemainingInSeconds})
      : super(listenable: timeRemainingInSeconds);

  final Animation<int> timeRemainingInSeconds;
  final String task;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String minutes =
        '${(timeRemainingInSeconds.value / 60).floor()}'.padLeft(2, '0');
    String seconds = '${(timeRemainingInSeconds.value % 60)}'.padLeft(2, '0');

    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        '$minutes:$seconds',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display2,
      ),
      subtitle: Text(task),
    );
  }
}

class TimerEntry extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final String task;
  final Duration duration;
  bool currentlyActive;

  TimerEntry({this.index, this.task, this.duration, this.currentlyActive});

  TimerEntryState createState() => TimerEntryState();
}

class TimerEntryState extends State<TimerEntry> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  AnimationController get controller {
    return _controller;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: widget.duration,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          child: TimedItem(
              task: widget.task,
              timeRemainingInSeconds: IntTween(
                      begin: controller.duration.inSeconds,
                      end: widget.currentlyActive ? 0 : widget.duration.inSeconds,
                    ).animate(controller)
                  ),
        ),
        toggleButton()
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget toggleButton() {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        controller.forward(from: 0.0);
        widget.currentlyActive = true;
      },
      child: widget.currentlyActive
          ? Icon(Icons.pause_circle_outline)
          : Icon(Icons.play_circle_outline),
    );
  }
}

class TimerList extends StatefulWidget {
  final int currentActiveTimer = 0;

  /// TODO: get them from outside
  final entries = <TimerEntry>[
    TimerEntry(
      index: 0,
      task: "The first task",
      duration: Duration(minutes: 3),
      currentlyActive: true,
    ),
    TimerEntry(
      index: 1,
      task: "Another task altogether",
      duration: Duration(minutes: 1),
      currentlyActive: false,
    )
  ];

  @override
  _TimerListState createState() => _TimerListState();
}

class _TimerListState extends State<TimerList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.entries.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return TimerEntry(
            task: widget.entries[index].task,
            duration: widget.entries[index].duration,
            currentlyActive: widget.entries[index].currentlyActive,
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Edit:
Here's a new version that works with a custom callback GetTaskButton but now I've lost access to my animation controller (see toggleButton function at the bottom). Is there a way to do it without moving the controller to the list class?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef Widget GetTaskButton(TimerEntry t);

class TimedItem extends AnimatedWidget {
  TimedItem({this.task, this.timeRemainingInSeconds})
      : super(listenable: timeRemainingInSeconds);

  final Animation<int> timeRemainingInSeconds;
  final String task;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String minutes =
        '${(timeRemainingInSeconds.value / 60).floor()}'.padLeft(2, '0');
    String seconds = '${(timeRemainingInSeconds.value % 60)}'.padLeft(2, '0');

    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        '$minutes:$seconds',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display2,
      ),
      subtitle: Text(task),
    );
  }
}

class TimerEntry extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final String task;
  final Duration duration;
  final GetTaskButton getButton;
  bool currentlyActive;

  TimerEntry({this.index, this.task, this.duration, this.currentlyActive, this.getButton});

  TimerEntryState createState() => TimerEntryState();
}

class TimerEntryState extends State<TimerEntry> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  AnimationController get controller {
    return _controller;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: widget.duration,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    return Text("test");
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          child: TimedItem(
              task: widget.task,
              timeRemainingInSeconds: IntTween(
                      begin: controller.duration.inSeconds,
                      end: widget.currentlyActive ? 0 : widget.duration.inSeconds,
                    ).animate(controller)
                  ),
        ),
        widget.getButton(widget)
      ],
    );
  }

}

class TimerList extends StatefulWidget {
  final int currentActiveTimer = 0;

  /// TODO: get them from outside
  final entries = <TimerEntry>[
    TimerEntry(
      index: 0,
      task: "The first task",
      duration: Duration(minutes: 3),
      currentlyActive: true,
    ),
    TimerEntry(
      index: 1,
      task: "Another task altogether",
      duration: Duration(minutes: 1),
      currentlyActive: false,
    )
  ];

  @override
  _TimerListState createState() => _TimerListState();
}

class _TimerListState extends State<TimerList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.entries.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return TimerEntry(
            task: widget.entries[index].task,
            duration: widget.entries[index].duration,
            currentlyActive: widget.entries[index].currentlyActive,
            getButton: (Widget tButton) => toggleButton(widget.entries[index]),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget toggleButton(TimerEntry t) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
        /// TODO: how to access this one?
//          t.controller.forward(from: 0.0);
          t.currentlyActive = !t.currentlyActive;
        });
      },
      child: t.currentlyActive
          ? Icon(Icons.pause_circle_outline)
          : Icon(Icons.play_circle_outline),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So For what i Understand: You need takeOut the List of TimerEntry (entries) out of the Class TimerList & Fetch the value from Outside ?

Answer (score 1):

*Here are Few things you can Do:*

Create a Global List variable.

```
List<TimerEntry> myEntries = List<TimerEntry>();
```

A function to add the Value in the myEntries List. I have hard-Coded the Values you can pass the Arguments to make it Dynamic.

```
void _addTimers() {
  myEntries.add(TimerEntry(
    index: 0,
    task: "The first task",
    duration: Duration(minutes: 3),
    currentlyActive: true,
  ));
  myEntries.add(TimerEntry(
    index: 1,
    task: "The Second task",
    duration: Duration(minutes: 3),
    currentlyActive: true,
  ));
}
```

You can Call the Function Whenever you need to Add the timer `_addTimers();`

In the Class TimerList - you need to Define a Constructor to get the List.

```
class TimerList extends StatefulWidget {
  final int currentActiveTimer = 0;
  final List<TimerEntry> entries;
  TimerList({this.entries});
```

& last you need the Pass the global List variable to the Class where you have Initialize it.

```
    body: TimerList(entries: myEntries,),
```

**update:**
Edited toggleButton() to make sure it responds correctly to the onTap().

```
Widget toggleButton() {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          controller.forward(from: 0.0);
          widget.currentlyActive = !widget.currentlyActive;
        });

      },
      child: widget.currentlyActive
          ? Icon(Icons.pause_circle_outline)
          : Icon(Icons.play_circle_outline),
    );
  }
```

**Update:** Passing AnimationController to Timer

```
class _TimerListState extends State<TimerList> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<AnimationController> myAnimationControllers =
      List<AnimationController>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getControllerList();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _getControllerList() {
    widget.entries.forEach((f) {
      myAnimationControllers
          .add(AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: f.duration));
    });
  }
```

Then in build pass it to TimerEntry:

```
TimerEntry(
       task: widget.entries[index].task,
       duration: widget.entries[index].duration,
       currentlyActive: widget.entries[index].currentlyActive,
       controller: myAnimationControllers[index]),
          )

class TimerEntry extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final String task;
  final Duration duration;
  bool currentlyActive;
  AnimationController controller;

  TimerEntry({
    this.index,
    this.task,
    this.duration,
    this.currentlyActive,
    this.controller,
  });
```

Comment: I should have removed this todo, since it's not part of my problem. Thanks, but I know how to get the list from outside. My question is how to move the 'toggleButton()' into TimerList instead of TimerEntry.

Comment: toggleButton() is returning Widget & part of the Tree, its no distinct advantage to take it out. Only On Pressed function can called from Outside.

Comment: thanks, but again, that doesn't answer my question. I'm looking for a way that a click on one button could potentially affect all timers in the list. For example I want to make sure only one timer can be active at a time. So starting one should stop the currently active one. That's why I thought it makes sense to have all this logic inside the list class instead of individual timers.

Comment: Then you should define the Controller in the TimerList & pass it as Argument to TimerEntry, this way you have control over each timer controller & you can have conditions & check if any controller is running stop it before running the new one.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the original post to include a callback function, so that's a first step I hope. However, is there a way around moving the Controller into TimerList? I'd like to keep the configurations of timers as open as possible. For example: allow 2 timers to run parallel but not more. But in such a case I need individual AnimationControllers for the TimerEntry and not just one on the TimerList. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You can have List<AnimationControllers> myAnimationControllers = List<AnimationControllers>(); & then add the value in it & then pass it to Timer . I updated the Code in my Answer.

Comment: Thanks! I made some changes to _getControllerList and now everything works the way I wanted it.
`void _getControllerList() {
    widget.entries.forEach((f) {
      final aController =
          AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: f.duration);
      myAnimationControllers.add(aController);
      f.controller = aController;
    });
  }`